# How can I upload my videos to the recommended encoding settings for YouTube?

Tags: youtube, codecs, openshot

I edited and exported a video using openshot, and selected the YouTube-HD profile. But, when uploading, I get the message saying:

> Your video will be processed faster if you encode them in a file format for video streaming. For more information, visit the Help Center.

Which I did, but I am having a hard time getting all the codes, and setting openshot properly!

- [Recommended upload encoding settings (advanced) - YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171)

I am running Ubuntu, Trusty Thar, 14.04, OpenShot 1.4.3.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/Encoding-for-YouTube-How-to-Get-the-Best-Results-83876.aspx).  But as long as you don't mind the extra processing time, I would keep the same format.

Comment: @Mitch That's a lot of reading! It stated their what the YouTube help center said also, to install the H.264 codec. Which I can't seem to find for Ubuntu. Plus I need it to work with openshot, Or - if needed - any other Linux Video Editor.

Comment: Take a look at [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), I use it all the time.

Comment: @Mitch, I completely forgot about HandBrake. I even had it installed xD. It did work though. I set the video according to the [YouTube help page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171) . Could you post it as an answer? Maybe add some more details to it? Thank for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HandBrake.  Handbrake is a tool for converting video from nearly any format to a selection of modern, widely supported codecs.  It converts video from nearly any format, and its free and Open Source.<sup>[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)</sup>

Handbrake makes converting videos in various formats, with the advantage of being a free open source tool. The program is compatible with devices such as Apple TV, iPod, iPhone, Xbox 360, PlayStation 3 and PSP.  It also gives you different settings like choosing exactly the type of audio coding (MP3, AAC, Vorbis AC3) and video (MPEG-4, Xvid, H.264, iPod, Baseline 1.3) the final file, to subtitle options and advanced video.

It has many preset formats to help you from the get go.

[image]